# Java application using JFileChooser , will work in Eclipse plug in or not?

Tags: java

I have written java application which uses JDT ,eclipse 3.6.1 and asks the user to choose a input file using JFileChooser. Now I want to convert this to eclipse plugin , whether JFileChooser will work in eclipse plugin?

Comment: I've never done this myself, but I don't why not.  Eclipse plug-ins work in the main UI thread, therefore JFileChooser should work.  I guess, the best way to check it would be to just try it.

Comment: I'm with Aleks on this one. And also: trial-and-error would most definitely give you an answer on that question. Any reason why you didn't try it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will.

Eclipse is based on SWT, but it doesn't mean you can't use Swing, which is provided by the JVM in which Eclipse usually is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but it may be troublesome, because eclipse usually abstarcts from teh actual file system through that ressource layer. If you use non-eclipse stuff like that filechooser, you'll always have to worry about keeping file system and eclipse's ressource layer in sync.